# Call to undefined function get_user_meta() in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have one file in wordpress theme folder. In that file I want to use `get_user_meta()` and `update_user_meta` function in that file. For which need to include. Because getting error:

> Call to undefined function get_user_meta()

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../wp-load.php' );

global $current_user;

wp_get_current_user();

$user_id= $current_user->ID;    

$user_data = get_user_meta($user_id);
$prev_reward_points = $user_data['reward_points'];
$new_reward_points = $prev_reward_points + 1000;

update_user_meta($user_id,"reward_points",$new_reward_points,$prev_reward_points);

echo "success";

exit;
```

Comment: add include_once('wp-load.php'); in your file

Answer (score 2):

Put below line in the starting of you file. Instead of

```
require( dirname( FILE ) . '/../../wp-load.php' );
```

Place  below code

```
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

May i know why you are using because it is not required all things can be done without creating any custom file.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I put include_once('wp-load.php');   But getting errors below                                             
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in <b>/home1/kclement/thingstodoinbaltimore.org/wp-content/themes/weddingvendor/addpoints.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />

Comment: No.What to do for it?

Comment: still Fatal error</b>:  Unsupported operand types in

Comment: show me the file structure where exactly file is located

Comment: it must work than. share that file's code here in your question

Comment: You check my answer no need to put dir name

Answer (score 0):

If this file is in your *theme* folder, then there is no need to include wp-load.php - instead, the "right" way to do this following WordPress best practices is:

1. Require this file inside of your theme (in your theme's functions.php file, add `require_once 'this_file.php';`)
2. Place your existing code inside of a function (see below - I've made some changes to prevent errors in your code).
3. Then, trigger this function in the manner that best suits your needs.  Since you don't explain what you're doing, it's hard to know how to coach you in this area.

   ```
   function calculate_new_reward_points() {

       global $current_user;

       wp_get_current_user();

       $user_id= $current_user->ID;

       // no need to do this way... simplified version below
       // $user_data = get_user_meta($user_id);

       // see documentation for get_user_meta - can load the value directly
       $prev_reward_points = (int)get_user_meta( $user_id, 'reward_points', TRUE );     

       $new_reward_points = $prev_reward_points + 1000;

       // This will NOT store two values the way you have done it - based on your code above, I've modified this line below to work properly
       // update_user_meta($user_id, "reward_points", $new_reward_points, $prev_reward_points);
       update_user_meta($user_id, "reward_points", $new_reward_points );

       echo "success";
   }
   ```

Now, instead of wherever you were calling the file originally, you simply call `calculate_new_reward_points();` - and you're done.